# PageLoaded Event Handler At Application Level

Tags: javascript, windows-8

In my Windows 8 application, I need to run some code when a page is loaded, but I need to run it at the application level in my default.js file.  Is there an event I can use to generically attach to when a page is loaded into the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In default.js, there's already a reference to [WinJS.Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229778.aspx), so you could do something like:

```
nav.addEventListener("navigated", function (e) { 
     console.log('loaded a new page ' + e.detail.location); 
});
```

That will fire when you navigate from page to page versus actually loading into the DOM (not sure how specific you mean that).

If you want to have something happen when you truly load a page into the DOM, you could add a override [load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770588.aspx) in your pages that then invoke a method on [WinJS.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229774.aspx), for example (Where the `unload` is part of the page code you get already generated)

```
    load: function()
    {
        WinJS.Application.doSomething();
    },

    unload: function () {
        this._items.dispose();
    },
```

and in the code for the application in app.js, you'd have

```
    app.doSomething = function () { console.log("I did something"); }
```

There's a glitch here though that I'm hunting down.  Once I override [load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770588.aspx), I'm seeing an HierarchyRequestError on the second invocation.